# Best way to incorporate a theme's code into MEAN.js application

Tags: meanjs

I am trying to incorporate all of the files (css, js, plugins) from a theme I purchased into a MEAN.js application I scaffolded out with yeoman. I am very unsure where to place the theme folders/how to call them in the layout.server.view.html page or even if that is the right page to be calling the files. Any suggestions would be great since I have not had much luck researching this topic on google.

Answer (score 3):

FOR MEANJS 0.4 : (did not tried but should work for meanjs 0.3)

I did a custom service to suits my needs. One default skin and the user can choose a personnal skin. Skins comes from [Bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com) and are free to use.

```
'use strict';

angular.module( 'core' )
  .service( 'ThemeService', [ 'Authentication', '$rootScope', '$document', '$q', '$timeout',
      function (Authentication, $rootScope, $document, $q, $timeout ) {

      var defaultTheme = 'flatly';
      var defaultPath = 'themes/';
      var defaultExtension = '.min.css';
      var defaultIgnore = 'require';
      var themes = [
        'bootstrap',
        'cerulean',
        'custom',
        'cyborg',
        'darkly',
        'flatly',
        'journal',
        'lumen',
        'paper',
        'readable',
        'sandstone',
        'simplex',
        'slate',
        'spacelab',
        'superhero',
        'united',
        'yeti'
      ];


      this.themes = themes;

      var loadCSS = function (href) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var style = $document[0].createElement('link');
        style.rel = 'stylesheet';
        style.type = 'text/css';
        style.href = href;
        style.onload = style.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
          $timeout(function () {
            deferred.resolve(e);
          });
        };
        style.onerror = function (e) {
          $timeout(function () {
            deferred.reject(e);
          });
        };
        $document[0].head.appendChild(style);
        return deferred.promise;
      };


      var theme = defaultTheme;
      if ( Authentication.user !== undefined )
        theme = Authentication.user.theme;



      var currentTheme = defaultTheme;

      var disableThemes = function (name) {
        var links = [];
        links = document.getElementsByTagName( 'link' );
        for ( var i = links.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
          if ( links[ i ].href.indexOf( defaultPath ) > -1 ){
            if( (links[ i ].href.indexOf( defaultPath + name ) === -1) && (links[ i ].href.indexOf( defaultPath + defaultIgnore ) === -1))
              links[ i ].disabled = true;
            else 
              links[ i ].disabled = false;
          }
        }
      };

      var enableTheme = function ( name ) {
        var links = [];
        links = document.getElementsByTagName( 'link' );
        for ( var i = links.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
          if ( links[ i ].href.indexOf( defaultPath + name ) > -1 )
            links[ i ].disabled = false;
          currentTheme = name;
        }
      };

      var loadTheme = function ( name ) {
        if ( themes.indexOf( name ) === -1 ) // Theme do not exist
          return false;
        if ( name === currentTheme ) // Theme is already the current theme
          return console.log('Current theme');

        loadCSS( defaultPath + name + defaultExtension ).then( function ( ) {
          disableThemes(name);
          currentTheme = name;
        } ).
        catch ( function () {
          loadTheme( defaultTheme );
        } );
      };

      this.loadTheme = loadTheme;

      loadTheme( theme );

      $rootScope.$on( 'themeChange', function (e, theme) {
        loadTheme( Authentication.user.theme );
      } );

    } ] );
```

To change the skin, you can just send an event : "themeChange" to the root scope like :

```
$rootScope.$emit( 'themeChange', 'readable' );
```

This should be called on skin change, and on login.

Additionally, you should add the personnal theme to the user model.

If you just aim to set ONE custom theme, edit `./config/assets/production.js` and `./config/assets/default.js`.

Else you can just add the CSS files into CSS folder of you client module.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this....But I can't tell you which one is right for you.

Create a theme folder within the public repository of the app and lets assume you use scss. In this theme folder, you can have a folder for scss, fonts, images. In the root of the theme folder, a parent scss file, which will call the partials of all files in the scss folder. Each partial could be named after a package. You get the gist.

Alternatively with mean package generator , and for each package you can have a css file in it. Mean.js will automatically compile all these files together , this is a grunt task `(clientCSS: ['public/modules/**/*.css'] ...)`

Both approaches work, your team's call to choose.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing this myself, it can get tricky depending on what you're trying to bring into your project.
The best way in my opinion is to keep things modular and stick to the conventions meanjs sets up. 
You can create a seperate folder for your themes css and reference those files inside of your default.js, just to stay organized.

Next, take a look at the plugins that are being used, theres a good chance you can use bower to include these packages/plugins into your project. Make sure you include these in your dependencies to use throughout your app.

Take a look at your current theme, see what you can put into directives (ex: navigation, side menu, sliders, etc.) that way you have organized reusable code. Build your views by using these directives throughout.

Do one thing at a time and you'll be able to slowly bring over a theme.
Good luck!